# HERE Maps: Change color of already travelled part of route

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to change the color of the route during navigation?
Specifically I would like the already travelled parts of the route to be a different color then the upcoming parts of the route. Right now it is all the same color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported with the 3.3.x generation of the HERE SDK.

This feature is something we are trying to add in an upcoming release, so stay tuned!

Comment: Is this feature available now, with premium sdk version 3.4? I want to remove the already travelled part of route.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the traveledColor variable of the MapRoute object to transparent did the trick for me.

```
mapRoute?.color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorAccent, null)
mapRoute?.traveledColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, android.R.color.transparent, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use  `Polyline` class to draw your path and then you can set color to it.

```
 Polyline line = googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng (myLocation2.getLatitude(), myLocation2.getLongitude()), new LatLng (currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())).width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: I'm actually doing it like this with HERE maps. I'm storing traveled positions and I draw a polyline.

Comment: Be careful of long routes with many points if you are drawing your own polyline on top. Apply something like a douglas peuker to simplify the shape points otherwise rendering performance will suffer.

Comment: I thought getRouteGeometry does that and returns simplified geometry already...hmmm

Comment: @DavidLeong Is this feature available now, with premium sdk version 3.4? I want to remove the already travelled part of route.